# Zoom to specific area by clicking on an element

Tags: d3.js, plot, zooming

I make a scatterplot using d3.js where the points are scattered according to their *name* and an accompanying *number*. The x axis displays the *group_1* once per group.

The data that is plotted would look like this:

```
name,   group_1, group_2, number
"a",   "A",     "1",     0.5
"b",   "A",     "1",    10.0
"c",   "A",     "1",     5.0
"d",   "A",     "2",     1.0
"e",   "A",     "2",     3.0
"f",   "A",     "2",    10.0
"g",   "B",     "1",     3.0
```

---

### Starting point.

The current code (based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25942478/1251007)/[example on bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/jsl6906/a8a4dd54f3d8de6a7aae)) ...

```js
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  offset = 7;

var chartData = [{
  name: "a",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 0.5
}, {
  name: "b",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 10
}, {
  name: "c",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 5.0
}, {
  name: "d",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 1.0
}, {
  name: "e",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 3.0
}, {
  name: "f",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 10.0
}, {
  name: "g",
  group_1: "B",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 3.0
}];

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(chartData.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  .rangePoints([0, width]);

var chartGroups = [];
chartData.forEach(function(d, i, array) {
  if (i === 0) d.first = true;
  else if (d.group_1 !== array[i - 1].group_1) d.first = true;
  if (i === array.length - 1) d.last = true;
  else if (d.group_1 !== array[i + 1].group_1) d.last = true;
  if (d.first) chartGroups.push({
    group: d.group_1,
    start: i === 0 ? x(d.name) : ((x(d.name) + x(array[i - 1].name)) / 2)
  });
  if (d.last) chartGroups[chartGroups.length - 1].end = i === array.length - 1 ? x(d.name) : ((x(d.name) + x(array[i + 1].name)) / 2);
});

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function(d) {
    return d.number;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickValues([])
  .outerTickSize(offset)
  .orient("bottom"),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll("circle.point")
  .data(chartData)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr({
    "class": "point",
    cx: function(d) {
      return x(d.name);
    },
    cy: function(d) {
      return y(d.number);
    },
    r: 5
  });

var groups = svg.selectAll("g.chartGroup")
  .data(chartGroups)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "chartGroup")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (height + offset) + ")");
groups.append("text")
  .attr({
    x: function(d) {
      return (d.start + d.end) / 2;
    },
    dy: "1em",
    "text-anchor": "middle"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.group;
  });
groups.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var t = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text").node().getBBox(),
      ttop = [t.x + t.width / 2, t.y];
    console.log(d, t, ttop);
    return "M" + d.start + ",0" + "V" + -offset;
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

```css
text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line,
g.chartGroup path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
circle.point {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

... generates this plot:

[image: initial plot]

### What I want to achieve.

**1. Zoom Level:**
I want zoom in to only display all elements of *A* (from *group_1*) when clicking on the label *A* on the x axis. Besides the zooming, also the labeling of the x axis should change to incorporate data from *group_2*.

[image: 1. zoom level]

**2. Zoom Level:**
On the 2. zoom level, this should be repeated. By clicking on *1* (from *group_2*), I want a zoom to all elements of this group. The x axis should change to incorporate data from *name*

[image: 2. zoom level]

### What I tried.

I tried adding basic zooming function (from [this example on bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892928)) through these code parts, but even this didn't work out:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    // ...
    .call(zoom);


function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}
```

The array `chartGroups`, which is based on *group_1* is an array of calculated start and end coordinates for displaying the groups on the x axis. But I can't figure out, how to use them for zooming.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  offset = 7;

var chartData = [{
  name: "a",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 0.5
}, {
  name: "b",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 10
}, {
  name: "c",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 5.0
}, {
  name: "d",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 1.0
}, {
  name: "e",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 3.0
}, {
  name: "f",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 10.0
}, {
  name: "g",
  group_1: "B",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 3.0
}];

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(chartData.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  .rangePoints([0, width]);

var chartGroups = [];
chartData.forEach(function(d, i, array) {
  if (i === 0) d.first = true;
  else if (d.group_1 !== array[i - 1].group_1) d.first = true;
  if (i === array.length - 1) d.last = true;
  else if (d.group_1 !== array[i + 1].group_1) d.last = true;
  if (d.first) chartGroups.push({
    group: d.group_1,
    start: i === 0 ? x(d.name) : ((x(d.name) + x(array[i - 1].name)) / 2)
  });
  if (d.last) chartGroups[chartGroups.length - 1].end = i === array.length - 1 ? x(d.name) : ((x(d.name) + x(array[i + 1].name)) / 2);
});

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function(d) {
    return d.number;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickValues([])
  .outerTickSize(offset)
  .orient("bottom"),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .y(y)
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(zoom);

svg.selectAll("circle.point")
  .data(chartData)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr({
    "class": "point",
    cx: function(d) {
      return x(d.name);
    },
    cy: function(d) {
      return y(d.number);
    },
    r: 5
  });

var groups = svg.selectAll("g.chartGroup")
  .data(chartGroups)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "chartGroup")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (height + offset) + ")");
groups.append("text")
  .attr({
    x: function(d) {
      return (d.start + d.end) / 2;
    },
    dy: "1em",
    "text-anchor": "middle"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.group;
  });
groups.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var t = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text").node().getBBox(),
      ttop = [t.x + t.width / 2, t.y];
    console.log(d, t, ttop);
    return "M" + d.start + ",0" + "V" + -offset;
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

function zoomed() {
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}
```

```css
text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line,
g.chartGroup path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
circle.point {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

### Question.

How can I zoom to specficic areas just by clicking on a text element?

### Edit.

As suggested in the comments, I tried to adjust the domain and redraw the circles. I did this the following way:

```
function zoom_update(group) {
    //adjust domain
    x.domain(chartData.map(function (d) {
        if (d.group_1 == group) {
            return d.name;
        }
    }));
    console.log(x.domain());
    svg.selectAll(".xaxis")
        .transition(750)
        .call(xAxis);

    // update circles
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .transition(750)
        .attr({
            cx: function (d) {return x(d.name);}
        });
}
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  offset = 7;

var chartData = [{
  name: "a",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 0.5
}, {
  name: "b",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 10
}, {
  name: "c",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 5.0
}, {
  name: "d",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 1.0
}, {
  name: "e",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 3.0
}, {
  name: "f",
  group_1: "A",
  group_2: "2",
  number: 10.0
}, {
  name: "g",
  group_1: "B",
  group_2: "1",
  number: 3.0
}];
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangePoints([0, width]);

x.domain(chartData.map(function(d) {
  return d.name;
}));

var chartGroups = [];
chartData.forEach(function(d, i, array) {
  if (i === 0) d.first = true;
  else if (d.group_1 !== array[i - 1].group_1) d.first = true;
  if (i === array.length - 1) d.last = true;
  else if (d.group_1 !== array[i + 1].group_1) d.last = true;
  if (d.first) chartGroups.push({
    group: d.group_1,
    start: i === 0 ? x(d.name) : ((x(d.name) + x(array[i - 1].name)) / 2)
  });
  if (d.last) chartGroups[chartGroups.length - 1].end = i === array.length - 1 ? x(d.name) : ((x(d.name) + x(array[i + 1].name)) / 2);
});

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function(d) {
    return d.number;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickValues([])
  .outerTickSize(offset)
  .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");



var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll("circle.point")
  .data(chartData)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr({
    "class": "point",
    cx: function(d) {
      return x(d.name);
    },
    cy: function(d) {
      return y(d.number);
    },
    r: 5
  });

var groups = svg.selectAll("g.chartGroup")
  .data(chartGroups)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "chartGroup")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (height + offset) + ")");
groups.append("text")
  .attr({
    x: function(d) {
      return (d.start + d.end) / 2;
    },
    dy: "1em",
    "text-anchor": "middle"
  })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    zoom_update(d.group);
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.group;
  });

groups.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var t = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text").node().getBBox(),
      ttop = [t.x + t.width / 2, t.y];
    console.log(d, t, ttop);
    return "M" + d.start + ",0" + "V" + -offset;
  });



svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "xaxis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "yaxis")
  .call(yAxis);

function zoom_update(group) {
  x.domain(chartData.map(function(d) {
    if (d.group_1 == group) {
      return d.name;
    }
  }));
  alert(x.domain());
  svg.selectAll(".xaxis")
    .transition(750)
    .call(xAxis);

  // update circles
  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition(750)
    .attr({
      cx: function(d) {
        return x(d.name);
      }
    });
}
```

```css
text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.xaxis path,
.xaxis line,
.yaxis path,
.yaxis line,
.axis path,
.axis line,
g.chartGroup path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
circle.point {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The log shows that the domain is set depending on which label is clicked. In addition, the circles that are outside the new domain are moved to `x=0`, but the remaining circles are not spread over the whole domain.

Comment: You don't need the zoom behaviour here. Zoom in this context is really only adjusting the domain of the scales and redrawing. So all you need to do is recompute the domain of the scales using only the data points of the group you're interested in and redraw.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Thanks for your input. I tried it the way you suggested (see edited question), but the plot is not updated. Is calling `.call(xAxis)` sufficient to redraw the plot? Or do I need something else/more?

Comment: You also have to reset the positions of all the circles.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Okay, I'm getting closer ... I updated my question again, now I'm stuck at resetting the circles.

Comment: You need to filter the domain values: http://jsfiddle.net/n7k4wg0b/